# Arduino sensor labels: "s" vs "out"

Tags: signal

On many Arduino sensors, there are most likely a port for, gnd, vcc, and signal/s. On some other sensors, I see there is an "out" replacing an "s". This confuses me because "s" normally goes in analog and output goes to Rx. I am deeply confused. What is the difference between "s" and "out"? I've tried looking at tutorials but all it says is attach "out" to rx. I have an "s" label and there are no other models like mine.

Comment: There is no standard for Arduino breakout signals. They will be labeled whatever the designer/manufacturer wants to. Therefore "s" and "out" can essentially mean any of the options you mentioned and neither will be "wrong".

Comment: Your best bet is to find out what the breakout consists of (i.e. a sensor with SPI, I2C, UART, RS485, Analog Out, PWM Out, or whatever interface) and work based on that instead of trusting the labels.

Comment: you are asking for help with the sensor that you have  but you do not say what you have ... do you see anything wrong with that?